# Sending a push notification while iPhone is starting up - notification not delivered to device

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, azure-notificationhub

We are getting reports from our testers that not all Apple Push Notifications are delivered. Specifically, **if a notification is sent while the target device is starting up** (booting up, establishing network connection, etc), then **the notification is never received**.

I understand that APNS delivers notifications on a best-effort basis. I've perused [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/APNSOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH8-SW1) which says the following regarding QoS:

> Apple Push Notification service includes a Quality of Service (QoS) component that performs a store-and-forward function. If APNs attempts to deliver a notification and the destination device is offline, APNs stores the notification for a limited period of time and delivers it when the device becomes available again. This component stores only the most recent notification per device and per app. If a device is offline, sending a notification request targeting that device causes the previous request to be discarded. If a device remains offline for a long time, all its stored notifications in APNs are discarded.

I've set the `apns-expiration` to 90 minutes to engage the QoS functionality.

Notifications **are** delivered when:

- The notification was sent while the device is switched on and operating normally.
- <strike>The notification was sent while the device was switched off (it is subsequently delivered a short time after the device is switched on).</strike>

As an aside, we're using template notifications with Azure Notification Hub to integrate with APNS. As such, our configuration for APNS expiration and priority looks like this:

```
registration = new AppleTemplateRegistrationDescription(deviceUpdate.Handle, PushNotifications.IosTemplate)
{
    Expiry = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(90).ToString("o"),
    Priority = "10"
};
```

How can I debug/troubleshoot this problem, has anybody encountered similar behaviour?

Comment: Kindly take a look at the article which helps identifies why notifications might get dropped or not be received by devices. It also explains how to determine the root cause. If you haven’t checked this already so, try the steps outlined the document to start with and isolate the issue -https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-push-notification-fixer

Comment: Thank you @AjayKumar-MSFT, this article is handy. If I upgrade to standard tier, I can query the Per Message Telemetry API. Can you tell me if I am setting the apns-expiration header correctly?

Comment: Typically, it is set this way:

var notification = new AppleNotification("json payload");

notification.Headers["X-Apns-Priority"] = "5"; // or "10", 

which is the default value

notification.Expiry = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1);
await hub.SendNotificationAsync(notification /* , optional-tags */);


You can find more samples here -https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/push-notification-hubs-apns-priority

Comment: Thanks again, I think I struggled because the `TemplateNotification` class hasn't got an Expiry property to control `apns-expiration`, which is fair enough. The article you've linked about the `apns-priority` header provides valuable clues. In fact, a better solution would be to tokenise the expiry in the template registration. i.e. `registration.Expiry = "$(Expiry)";`. I'm going to give this a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Addressed this behaviour by adding the following headers to each template notification:

```
var templateProperties = new Dictionary<string, string> {
    // omitted
};

var notification = new TemplateNotification(templateProperties);

notification.Headers.Add("ServiceBusNotification-Apns-Expiry", DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(7).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mmzzz"));
notification.Headers.Add("apns-expiration", DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(7).ToUnixTimeSeconds().ToString());

await hubClient.SendNotificationAsync(notification, destinationTags);
```

And removed the `Expiry` property from the initialisation of `AppleTemplateRegistrationDescription`:

```
var apnsHeaders = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "apns-priority", "10" } };
registration = new AppleTemplateRegistrationDescription(deviceUpdate.Handle, PushNotifications.IosTemplate, apnsHeaders)
{
    Priority = "10"
};
```

It was useful to take a look at the [Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs-dotnet) source on GitHub.

Comment: Glad to know the issue is resolved. Thanks for sharing the solution that worked for you.